# Is "Failed to modify image attribute" issue due to incorrect permission?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, aws-organizations

I'm trying to share an AMI with a few Organization Units, but getting the below error while sharing.
`Failed to modify image attribute. Invalid attribute item value "<ARN_OF_THE_OU>" for OrganizationArn item type.`

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause of an issue, that's an incorrect ARN format of OU

> ARN format – When you specify an organization or OU in command, make sure to use the correct ARN format. You'll get an error if you specify only the ID, for example, if you specify only o-123example or ou-1234-5example.
>
> Correct ARN formats:
>
> Organization ARN: `arn:aws:organizations::account-id:organization/organization-id`
>
> OU ARN: `arn:aws:organizations::account-id:ou/organization-id/ou-id`